# Javascript:: Play multiple audio files via HTML5 Audio Player playlist

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I'm currently working on a code to play HTML5 audio file(s).

Let start with the code first so it would be easier to explain.

Here is my code :

```
<style>
.btn
{
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:25px;
    width:25px
}

.play:after
{
    content:">"
}

.pause:after
{
    content:"||"
}
</style>

<button class="btn play" id=HeziGangina-Gravity></button>
<button class="btn play" id=HeziGangina-PUG></button>

<script>


iBtn=document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(j=0;j<iBtn.length;j++)
{
    iBtn[j].addEventListener
    (
        'click',
        function()
        {
            var audio=new Audio(this.id+'.mp3');

            if(audio.pause)
            {
                audio.play();       
                iBtn[j].classList.remove("play");
                iBtn[j].classList.add("pause");
            }
            else
            {
                audio.pause();
                iBtn[j].classList.remove("pause");
                iBtn[j].classList.add("play");
            }

        },false
    );
}

</script>
```

My current script is working just fine to play the selected audio file but I still have 2 issues to be solved.

1. I want to be able to change the class name on the current pressed button from play to pause and Vice Versa.
2. I want to be able to completely disable all other audio file(s) (only) when other track is selected.

[optional]::Is it possible to create ogg audio file fallback with pure javascript (as the same as stacking `<source>` tags with html)?

Comment: tip : `this` in the function(){} after the event points to the clicked button. Just use `this.className = "foo"` to replace the class name.

Comment: I prefer pure JavaScript.

Comment: One question per question, please, and update your title to reflect the one you chose. A list of tags isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your audio.pause to audio.paused
2. Before play the new track pause all tracks

   ```
   if(audio.paused) {
     var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

     for (i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
       audios[i].pause();
     }

     audio.play();       
     iBtn[j].classList.remove("play");
     iBtn[j].classList.add("pause");
   } else {
     audio.pause();
     iBtn[j].classList.remove("pause");
     iBtn[j].classList.add("play");
   }
   ```

Hope it will help you.

As for your optional question, you can check the browser using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser). And make an if statement when you create the Audio to check the browser. So if it's [IE or Safari](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp), load mp3, else, load ogg.